# OnBackPress Not working for Fragment in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, onbackpressed

How can we get the `onBackPressed` callback only in the fragment class? Instead ,now it is going to the `onBackPressed` in the activity classes?  I need to restrict sending the callback to Activity on backpress from fragment.

example::

```
 @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
            Log.d("SKT", "backPressHere");
        }
```

Comment: Fragment doesn't have onBackPressed method to override. You need to implement this in Activity.

Answer (score 0):

Implement this in the Activity and restriction part you can handle via the interface.

Comment: As per my requirement, I'm having the fragment class in my module which I was creating. so there is no activity class written in my module, since I have used singleton classes for showing the fragment class . so I have to control the `backPress` on the fragment itself, instead of handling it in activity. The intention of creating it as `SDK` is that, user can plug the `SDK` into any application and should able to run it.

Answer (score 0):

The fragment itself does not have a return button, but instead you can put this code in the onBackPressed() method in the activity to which the fragment is attached, and with the getSupportFragmentManager() method you can control the examples of running fragments or delete and return do.

here is example :

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    int count = getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();   
    if (count == 0) {
             // no fragment attach
             super.onBackPressed();
    } else {
        // fragment attach
        getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The fragment does not receive the `onBackPressed` callback. You should implement dispatching the event in the activity.

```
public interface BackPressedSupport{
    /**
     * return true if the fragment consumed the event. otherwise false.
     */
    boolean onBackPressed();
}
```

In your Activity :

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Fragment f = getActiveFragment();
    if (f instanceof BackPressedSupport && (BackPressedSupport f).onBackPressed()){
        return;
    }

    super.onBackPressed();
    // Other backPressed handling of activity.
    
}

public Fragment getActiveFragment() {
    if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() == 0) {
        return null;
    }
    String tag = getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryAt(getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() - 1).getName();
    return getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tag);
}
```

In your Fragment:

```
public MyFragment extends Fragment implements BackPressedSupport {
    /* Your code */
    @Override
    public boolean onBackPressed() {
        /* Handle backpressed */
        Log.d("SKT", "backPressHere");

        return true ; // tell the activity to stop handling this backPressed event
        // return false; // keep the default behaviour 
    }

}
```